# How to catch the exceptions thrown inside an actor?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

In my actor, the methods may throw exception:

```
class ServerActor extends Actor {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case "Start" =>
      println("### actor started")
      throw new Exception("My exception when starting")
    case msg =>
      println("### actor get other message: " + msg)
      throw new Exception("another exception for other messages: " + msg)
  }
}
```

Is there any way to handle all the exception in a single place? I want to handle them together, e.g. logging them

Comment: Don't handle it. Let it crash!

Comment: You want to just log the exception or recover?

Comment: @tariksbl maybe just logging

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you can try to do this in parent under supervision strategy:
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/fault-tolerance.html

Or you have this method on actor:

`def preRestart(reason: Throwable, message: Option[Any]): Unit`

where *reason* is the exception that caused the actor to crash.